# A little issue with c homework

Tags: c

[The equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIAlv.png)

Hello guys, I have a homework to do with c and it's giving me some problems.
So basically I have to make a program that will give me the result for this particular equation, here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a;
    printf("a:\t");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    double x,y;
    double z = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
        if(i==3){continue;}
        double m=1;
        for(int n=i;n<=17;n++)
        {
            if(n=12){continue;}
            x=(pow(n,3)-8)/(n-12);
            m *=x;
            printf("i = %d'de n = %d iken %f\n", i,n,m);
        }
        y=pow(fabs(7-a),i)/pow(i-3,5);
        z+=y;
        printf("i = %d ise %f\n", i, y);
    }
    printf("W = %f\n", z);
}
```

I have used some very similar codes with other equations but this one has been very problematic.
It asks me to type "a" and waits there without doing anything even when I type it.

So if anyone can point out what's wrong with my code I would be very happy.

Comment: This: `if(n=12){continue;}` will set the looping variable `n` to 12 and continue. That means that `n` will never reach 17. Remember that in C, `=` is assignment; `==` is a comparison. Your code is legal C, but when I enable warning, the compiler suggests to put extra brackets around `n=12` to make clear that it is an assignment.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo. Enable compiler warnings...

Answer (score 3):

`if(n=12)` should be

```
if(n==12)
```

otherwise you wil have an infinite loop